# Не понимаю почему не работает логическое ИЛИ

Tags: python, list

В `firstfold` остается один елемент - `6` и в `12` строке `elif len(secondfold) >= 1 or len(firstfold) >= 1: surject = False` должно выполнится условие `surject = False`, но оно не выполняется, почему?

```
firstfold = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
secondfold = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i in firstfold.copy():#удаляет общее елементы
    if i in secondfold:
        try:
            firstfold.remove(i)
            secondfold.remove(i)
        except ValueError: continue

print(firstfold, secondfold)
if len(secondfold) == 0 or len(firstfold) == 0: surject = True
elif len(secondfold) >= 1 or len(firstfold) >= 1: surject = False
print(surject)
```

Comment: Потому что выполняется `len(secondfold) == 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if len(secondfold) == 0 or len(firstfold) == 0: 
    surject = True
elif len(secondfold) >= 1 or len(firstfold) >= 1: 
    surject = False
```

давайте разбираться

во первых что надо знать - **как только выполняется условие, остальные условия не рассматриваются**

итак в начале `len(firstfold) = 1`, `len(secondfold) = 0`

начинает проверяться в `if`

```
if len(secondfold) == 0 or len(firstfold) == 0:
```

первая часть условия

```
len(secondfold) == 0
```

оно истинное (`True`)

по идее на этом проверка заканчивается, потому что значение второй части условия

```
len(firstfold) == 0
```

не важна

и выполняется код:

```
surject = True
```

поскольку первое условие выполнено (истинно), то второе условие (в `ifelse`) уже не рассматривается и код под условием не выполняется

P.S.

кстати ваш код можно было бы реализовать так:

```
firstfold = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
secondfold = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]

arr1 = [i for i in firstfold if i not in secondfold]
arr2 = [i for i in secondfold if i not in firstfold]

firstfold, secondfold = arr1, arr2
```

дешево и сердито :)

или даже так:

```
firstfold = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
secondfold = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]

firstfold, secondfold = set(firstfold).difference(secondfold), set(secondfold).difference(firstfold)
```